# Sort IP with jQuery Datatables

Tags: jquery, ip, datatables

I'm using Datatables with jQuery.
My table includes this header:
`host` `type` `records`
Some entrie can in this table can look like this:

```
www   A    192.168.1.122
ftp   A    17.5.16.12
```

My problem now is, that Datatables sorts the IPs wrong.
Any ideas how to get this right?

Comment: try `tablesorter`. NOTE! tablesorter will auto-detect most data types including numbers, dates, ip-adresses for more information see Examples http://tablesorter.com/docs/#Examples

Comment: @BMW Thanks for your reply, but I i need to use datatables. Do you know a solution for datatables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a sorting plugin for datatables which can sort IP Addresses.

Check [Datatables Sort](http://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting).

You can also put check boxes in each row and then perform actions on the ones which have been selected through the API - for more on the API see http://datatables.net/api

Edit-
Was this option added to your code?

```
"aoColumns": [
                null,
                { "sType": 'string-ip' },
                null
            ]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply too. I tried this one, but it sorts not correctly.

Comment: @Sylnois Could you show me what you have tried.For more information refer https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/16558/sorting-ip-address/p1,http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/9658/sorting-on-ip-address/p1

Comment: I found my mistake...... I generate the ip list with jquery. I added accidentally a breakline to every ip :D